# Spring: method to validate whole object

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Let's say I defined my `Entity` class with some validation annotations:

```
public class Entity {
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String login;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @Email
    private String email;
}
```

I know that a new `Entity` can be validated using the `@Valid` annotation in the argument, and the associated error object.

However, I need to create a new `Entity` in the middle of a different method and I need to validate that the constructed entity is correct (it matches the restrictions declared with annotations in the definition of the class):

```
public whateverMethod(...) {
    Entity e = new Entity(a, b, c, ...);
    validate(e); // I need something like this
}
```

I can't find anything like this in the Spring documentation.

Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate: how to validate a constructed object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838424/hibernate-how-to-validate-a-constructed-object)

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a `Validator` object by using the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` and then use that validator to validate your entity.

Bean declaration :

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

Your service :

```
@Service
public class fooService {

    @Autowired
    Validator validator

    public whateverMethod(...) {
        Entity e = new Entity(a, b, c, ...);
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Entity>> = validator.validate(e); 
    }
}
```

If you don't want to inject the bean, you can do something like this :

```
public class fooClass {

    public whateverMethod(...) {
        Entity e = new Entity(a, b, c, ...);

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Entity>> = validator.validate(e); 
    }
}
```

Note that a `JSR-303` provider, such as `Hibernate Validator`, is expected to be present in the classpath and will be detected automatically.